# sklearn train_test_split on pandas stratify by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm a relatively new user to `sklearn` and have run into some unexpected behavior in `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection`. I have a pandas `dataframe` that I would like to split into a training and test set. I would like to `stratify` my data by at least 2, but ideally 4 columns in my `dataframe`.

There were no warnings from `sklearn` when I tried to do this, however I found later that there were repeated rows in my final data set. I created a sample test to show this behavior:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
a = np.array([i for i in range(1000000)])
b = [i%10 for i in a]
c = [i%5 for i in a]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c})
```

It seems to work as expected if I stratify by either column:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=df[['b']])
print(len(train.a.values))  # prints 800000
print(len(set(train.a.values)))  # prints 800000

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=df[['c']])
print(len(train.a.values))  # prints 800000
print(len(set(train.a.values)))  # prints 800000
```

But when I try to `stratify` by both columns, I get repeated values:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=df[['b', 'c']])
print(len(train.a.values))  # prints 800000
print(len(set(train.a.values)))  # prints 640000
```

Answer (score 62):

If you want `train_test_split` to behave as you expected (stratify by multiple columns with no duplicates), create a new column that is a concatenation of the values in your other columns and stratify on the new column.

```
df['bc'] = df['b'].astype(str) + df['c'].astype(str)
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=df[['bc']])
```

If you're worried about collision due to values like `11` and `3` and `1` and `13` both creating a concatenated value of `113`, then you can add some arbitrary string in the middle:

```
df['bc'] = df['b'].astype(str) + "_" + df['c'].astype(str)
```

Comment: This is a brutal hack, with the issues you described (possible collisions...), but for now, it seems the only way. Using e.g. `df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple)` raises `ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead.`

Comment: A similar approach (but more efficient) would be to use numpy to encode the columns to stratify by. With `np.unique(df[['b', 'c']], axis=0, return_inverse=True)` you give each different combination its own new id, which then can be used as the stratify parameter. This way there's no need to convert types or slow string look ups

Answer (score 37):

The reason you're getting duplicates is because `train_test_split()` eventually defines strata as the *unique set of values* of whatever you passed into the `stratify` argument.  Since strata are defined from two columns, one row of data may represent more than one stratum, and so sampling may choose the same row twice because it thinks it's sampling from different classes.

The `train_test_split()` function [calls](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L1700) `StratifiedShuffleSplit`, which [uses](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L1254) `np.unique()` on `y` (which is what you pass in via `stratify`).  From the source code:

```
classes, y_indices = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
n_classes = classes.shape[0]
```

Here's a simplified sample case, a variation on the example you provided:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 20
a = np.arange(N)
b = np.random.choice(["foo","bar"], size=N)
c = np.random.choice(["y","z"], size=N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c})

print(df)
     a    b  c
0    0  bar  y
1    1  foo  y
2    2  bar  z
3    3  bar  y
4    4  foo  z
5    5  bar  y
...
```

The stratification function thinks there are four classes to split on: `foo`, `bar`, `y`, and `z`.  But since these classes are essentially nested, meaning `y` and `z` both show up in `b == foo` and `b == bar`, we'll get duplicates when the splitter tries to sample from each class.

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, 
                               stratify=df[['b', 'c']])
print(len(train.a.values))  # 16
print(len(set(train.a.values)))  # 12

print(train)
     a    b  c
3    3  bar  y   # selecting a = 3 for b = bar*
5    5  bar  y
13  13  foo  y
4    4  foo  z
14  14  bar  z
10  10  foo  z
3    3  bar  y   # selecting a = 3 for c = y
6    6  bar  y
16  16  foo  y
18  18  bar  z
6    6  bar  y
8    8  foo  y
18  18  bar  z
7    7  bar  z
4    4  foo  z
19  19  bar  y

#* We can't be sure which row is selecting for `bar` or `y`, 
#  I'm just illustrating the idea here.
```

There's a larger design question here: Do you want to used nested stratified sampling, or do you actually just want to treat each class in `df.b` and `df.c` as a separate class to sample from?  If the latter, that's what you're already getting.  The former is more complicated, and that's not what `train_test_split` is set up to do.

You might find [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22662/stratified-sampling-with-multiple-variables) of nested stratified sampling useful.

Answer (score 11):

What version of scikit-learn are you using ? You can use `sklearn.__version__` to check.

The prior to version 0.19.0, scikit-learn does not handle 2-dimensional stratification correctly. It is patched in 0.19.0.

It is describled in [issue #9044](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9044).

Update your scikit-learn should fix the problem. If you can't update your scikit-learn, see this commit history [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/93563b0ac1d96403eff9988dfcb680d42c6304aa) for the fix.

Comment: What does "correctly" mean here? Does it mean that it performs the nested stratified sampling that andrew_reece mentioned?

Comment: I just tested it, and it seems that it does indeed do the nested stratified sampling. Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful!

Comment: Sklearn does not handle 2-dimensional stratification AT ALL (0.22 here). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508036/sklearn-stratifiedkfold-valueerror-supported-target-types-are-binary-mul - so this only works for one-hot vectors, not for feature tuples! Probalby the string-concat-hack above is the only way for now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iteratively split your data. There's a class for it in scikit-multilearn. Bit annoying that it only works on NumPy arrays but what can you do?

Here's a function that should do what you are asking for:

```py
import pandas as pd
from skmultilearn.model_selection import IterativeStratification

def iterative_split(df, test_size, stratify_columns):
    """Custom iterative train test split which
    'maintains balanced representation with respect
    to order-th label combinations.'

    From https://madewithml.com/courses/mlops/splitting/#stratified-split
    """
    # One-hot encode the stratify columns and concatenate them
    one_hot_cols = [pd.get_dummies(df[col]) for col in stratify_columns]
    one_hot_cols = pd.concat(one_hot_cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
    stratifier = IterativeStratification(
        n_splits=2, order=len(stratify_columns), sample_distribution_per_fold=[test_size, 1-test_size])
    train_indices, test_indices = next(stratifier.split(df.to_numpy(), one_hot_cols))
    # Return the train and test set dataframes
    train, test = df.iloc[train_indices], df.iloc[test_indices]
    return train, test

example = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]*8*2, 'b': [4, 5, 6, 7]*6*2, 'c': [7, 8]*12*2})
train, test = iterative_split(example, 0.4, ['a', 'b'])
# print(f'{train =}')
# print(f'{test =}')

print(f'{train[["a"]].value_counts() =}')
print(f'{test[["a"]].value_counts()  =}')
print(f'{train[["b"]].value_counts() =}')
print(f'{test[["b"]].value_counts()  =}')
```

Output

```
train[["a"]].value_counts() =a
1    10
2    10
3    10
dtype: int64
test[["a"]].value_counts()  =a
1    6
2    6
3    6
dtype: int64
train[["b"]].value_counts() =b
5    8
6    8
4    7
7    7
dtype: int64
test[["b"]].value_counts()  =b
4    5
7    5
5    4
6    4
dtype: int64
```

And for your example we can add this code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([i for i in range(10_000)])
b = [i%10 for i in a]
c = [i%5 for i in a]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c})

train, test = iterative_split(df, test_size=0.2, stratify_columns=['b', 'c'])

print(len(train.a.values))  # prints 8000
print(len(set(train.a.values)))  # prints 8000
```

The `one_hot_cols` becomes a matrix of 1e6 x 3e5 in your example and that was a bit much. If someone comes up with a better way then I am all ears.