# Sklearn StratifiedKFold: ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Working with Sklearn stratified kfold split, and when I attempt to split using multi-class, I received on error (see below).  When I tried and split using binary, it works no problem.

```python
num_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))
y_train_categorical = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
kf=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=999)

# splitting data into different folds
for i, (train_index, val_index) in enumerate(kf.split(x_train, y_train_categorical)):
    x_train_kf, x_val_kf = x_train[train_index], x_train[val_index]
    y_train_kf, y_val_kf = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]

ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead.
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`keras.utils.to_categorical` produces a one-hot encoded class vector, i.e. the `multilabel-indicator` mentioned in the error message. `StratifiedKFold` is not designed to work with such input; from the `split` method [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.split):

> **`split`**(X, y, groups=None)
>
> [...]
>
> **y** : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
>
> The target variable for supervised learning problems. Stratification is done based on the y labels.

i.e. your `y` must be a 1-D array of your class labels.

Essentially, what you have to do is simply to invert the order of the operations: split first (using your intial `y_train`), and convert `to_categorical` afterwards.

Comment: i din't think that this is a good idea, because in a unbalanced dataset with multi-class classiffication problem, maybe the validation part what you want to convert it's labels doesn't contain all the classes. So, when you call to_categorical(val, n_class) it will raise an error ..

Comment: @Minion this is not correct; `StratifiedKFold` takes care that "*The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class*" ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)). In very special cases where some of the classes are very under-represented some extra caution (and manual checks) is obviously recommended, but the answer here is about the general case only and not for other, hypothetical ones...

Comment: Good, thanx for clarififcation .. just to ensure

Comment: I have tried inverting the order, and still get the same error. Any ideas? I have made a topic for my problem, if you could check that, thanks.

Comment: @Murilo please open a new question with the details and a minimum reproducible example; link here if necessary

Answer (score 12):

If your target variable is continuous then use simple KFold cross validation instead of StratifiedKFold.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 11):

Call to `split()` like this:

```
for i, (train_index, val_index) in enumerate(kf.split(x_train, y_train_categorical.argmax(1))):
    x_train_kf, x_val_kf = x_train[train_index], x_train[val_index]
    y_train_kf, y_val_kf = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]
```

Answer (score 9):

I bumped into the same problem and found out that you can check the type of the target with this `util` function:

```
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
type_of_target(y)

'multilabel-indicator'
```

From its docstring:

> - 'binary': `y` contains <= 2 discrete values and is 1d or a column
>     vector.
> - 'multiclass': `y` contains more than two discrete values, is not a
>     sequence of sequences, and is 1d or a column vector.
> - 'multiclass-multioutput': `y` is a 2d array that contains more
>     than two discrete values, is not a sequence of sequences, and both
>     dimensions are of size > 1.
> - 'multilabel-indicator': `y` is a label indicator matrix, an array
>     of two dimensions with at least two columns, and at most 2 unique
>     values.

With `LabelEncoder` you can transform your classes into an 1d array of numbers (given your target labels are in an 1d array of categoricals/object):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(target_labels)
```

Comment: Don't know the reason but it actually didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Complementing what @desertnaut said, in order to convert your `one-hot-encoding` back to 1-D array you will only need to do is:

```
class_labels = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
```

This will convert back to the initial representation of your classes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `x` was a 2D matrix, and `y` was also a 2d matrix, i.e. indeed a multi-class multi-output case. I just passed a dummy `np.zeros(shape=(n,1))` for the `y` and the `x` as usual. Full code example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 7], [9, 4]])
# y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]) # <<< works
y = X # does not work if passed into `.split`
rskf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=3, random_state=36851234)
for train_index, test_index in rskf.split(X, np.zeros(shape=(X.shape[0], 1))):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Comment: What is the point of using `StratifiedKFold` if you do not pass the labels to it? Simply use `KFold` instead.

Comment: `StratifiedKFold` would normally use the target, but in my particular shortcut, I'm passing 0's for the target, so you're right