# Error: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass')

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, sequential

How to handle the error `ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous-multioutput' instead` ?

I tried something with `from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target` or `x[0],y[0]`, but without success ...

#### Vizualization of X:

[image]

#### Vizualization of Y:

[image]

```py
X.shape, Y.shape
```

((336, 10), (336, 5))

#### Deep learning model:

```py
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=20, 
                kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),
                kernel_initializer=VarianceScaling(), 
                activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(5, 
                kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01),
                kernel_initializer=VarianceScaling(),                 
                activation='sigmoid'))
    
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['acc'])
    
    model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=50, batch_size=25, verbose = 0,
              validation_data=(X[test], Y[test]))

    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[2], scores[2]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[2] * 100)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous-multioutput' instead.
```

Comment: `StratifiedKFold` cannot split multilabel targets. A possible solution is suggested here: [Sklearn StratifiedKFold: ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508036/sklearn-stratifiedkfold-valueerror-supported-target-types-are-binary-mul)

Comment: I tried, but was unsuccessful, could you exemplify the data I provided?

Comment: See my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StratifiedKFold` is not meant to be used for multilabel targets as already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508036/sklearn-stratifiedkfold-valueerror-supported-target-types-are-binary-mul). It needs a 1D-array to determine how to split the indices.

I suppose you want to split your target based on the label with the highest probability. One way to achieve this goal would be to create a 1D-array indicating the target with the highest probability and pass this one to `StratifiedKFold` instead of the multilabel target.

Let's say you have your sample data in a pandas DataFrame `y` and it looks like this:

```
       0      1    2    3    4
0  0.966  0.000  0.0  0.2  0.0
1  0.966  0.000  0.0  0.0  0.2
2  0.000  0.966  0.5  0.0  0.0
3  0.000  0.966  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.966  0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Then, create a new object with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to find the target with highest probability:

```
y_max = y.idxmax(axis=1)
```

This gives you an output like this:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Now you can pass this array to `StratifiedKFold` and obtain the indices you need:

```
for train, test in kfold.split(X, y_max):
    ...

    model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=50, batch_size=25, verbose = 0,
              validation_data=(X[test], Y[test]))

    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[2], scores[2]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[2] * 100)
```

This way, you can obtain the indices from a 1D-array and still use the original data for training and testing. If your data happens to be in a numpy array, the same can be achieved with numpy's [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but when testing as mentioned, returned output: `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 336]`

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Comment: `[6, 336]` is interesting. If it was `[5, 336]` I could have guessed there is something wrong with the axis... Can you confirm the error is pointing to the split function again? What is the shape and content of your resulting 1D-array? Is it a numpy array or a pandas Series?

Comment: My Y is a pandas dataframe `pd.DataFrame (Y) .idxmax (axis = 1)`

Comment: `Length: 336, dtype: int64`

Comment: Does this help you or do you need any more information?

Comment: After some tests, I managed, it seems that the problem was with the installation of keras

Comment: If I wanted the number of periods to be set to 60, can you tell me how it would look?