# One Hot Encoded Labels and Stratified K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to implement Stratified K-fold cross validation on my ResNet-50 model.
Unforunately, I get this error when I one-hot encode my labels and try to split my data using stratified k fold:
`TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.`

The one-hot encoder has been implemented like so:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(Y)
Y = enc.transform(Y)
Y.toarray()
```

If i don't one-hot encode my labels, I get this error from fitting my model:
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible`

This is the code for implementing Stratified K-fold:

```
for train, test in skf.split(X, Y):
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dropout(0.7)(x)
  predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation= 'softmax')(x)
  model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = predictions)
  adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
  model.compile(optimizer= adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

  # Training
  history = model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs = 100, batch_size = 16)
```

where num_classes = 4.

So my question is:

> Q: How do I get one-hot encoded labels to work with skf.split()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is the model not accepting a `sparse matrix` as the result from using OneHotEncoding (which is the general intended behavior), you can try and change the OneHotEncoding model by setting its parameter `sparse=False`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
enc.fit(Y)
Y = enc.transform(Y)
```

Comment: Thank you! this answers my question however i have bumped into another problem.ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead. And it seems a post exists for this problem here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508036/sklearn-stratifiedkfold-valueerror-supported-target-types-are-binary-mul)

Comment: I don't see in your code where `multilabel-indicator` is being defined, but if it is a multiclass problem, then change it to `multiclass`.

Comment: It seems that the OneHotEncoder returns a multilabel-indicator. When i change my encoding to multiclass, should the output in my CNN contain only 1 node as result?

Comment: No, if you are using a softmax, it should contain as many output nodes as classes.