# Sklearn Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a multiclass problem (12 classes) and i am using [LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) to "one-hot-encode" my output. I was trying to use the LabelBinarizer first, then split the data using StratifiedKfold, but got that error:

```
Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead
```

Bumped into a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508036/sklearn-stratifiedkfold-valueerror-supported-target-types-are-binary-mul) (he uses Keras to_categorical instead) but the solution given (perform first the StratifiedKFold splits, then convert the output variables with LabelBinarizer) did not work for me. Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

df = pd.read_csv(...)
# Inputs and Outputs
x = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df['out'].values
# Split into train and test
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
# 5-fold StratifiedCV
n_splits = 5
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
# One-hot-output
label_bin = LabelBinarizer()
y_one_hot = label_bin.fit_transform(y_train)
# RF Classifier
classifier_RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,
                                       criterion='entropy',
                                       min_samples_split=2,
                                       min_samples_leaf=1,
                                       random_state=1)

metrics = ['f1_macro', 'f1_weighted',
            'precision_macro', 'precision_weighted',
            'recall_macro', 'recall_weighted',
            'roc_auc_ovr', 'roc_auc_ovr_weighted']

# CV
cv_results = cross_validate(classifier_RF,
                            x_train,
                            y_one_hot,
                            cv=kfold,
                            scoring=metricas,
                            verbose=10)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead.
```

Shapes before LabelBinarizer:

```
x_train = (4902644, 48)
y_train = (4902644,)
x_test = (1225661, 48)
y_test = (1225661,)
```

Shapes after LabelBinarizer:

```
y_one_hot = (4902644, 12)
```

Any ideas how can i fix this?